# Translate a web page click to a URL for wget

Tags: wget

I use a web page that a client uses to send me large files.

It's in tha far east, so it often requires dozens of attempts to work.

I'd like to script this using bash with wget (or curl) to retry until it succeeds.

The web page has a "Download" button with this:

```
<a class="button file-node-download" href="#">
                    Download
                </a>
```

The web page address is `https://aaa.bbbbbb.com/p/DWk8R34Qgj0Yof4D`.

The filename is `the_file.zip`.

I click on the button with the `href='#'` and the browser starts the download.

When I try this in bash all I get is the web page HTML:

```
wget 'https://aaa.bbbbbb.com/p/DWk8R34Qgj0Yof4D#'
wget 'https://aaa.bbbbbb.com/p/DWk8R34Qgj0Yof4D%23'
wget 'https://aaa.bbbbbb.com/p/DWk8R34Qgj0Yof4D%23the_file.zip'
wget 'https://aaa.bbbbbb.com/p/DWk8R34Qgj0Yof4D%23/the_file.zip'
```

I can't see any JavaScript on the page that might make this work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there's an event listener attached to the A DOM element. You'd need to find it and see what it actually does before you can get a working `wget` version out of it.

Have a look at the network tab in your browser's development console. You should be able to see what network request is eventually triggered by the click.